# SQL Query ignores controls that it refrences

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Form that contains a ListBox that gets data from the following query:

```
SELECT tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR AS [Retro Frei], 
tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status], 
tblISIN_Country_Table.Country

FROM 
(tblFUNDS INNER JOIN tblISIN_Country_Table ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblISIN_Country_Table.ISIN) 
INNER JOIN tblMorningstar_Data ON 
(tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection = tblMorningstar_Data.Fund_Selection) 
AND (tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblMorningstar_Data.ISIN)

GROUP BY tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, 
tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status], 
tblISIN_Country_Table.Country, tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection

HAVING (((tblFUNDS.RDR) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnRDR],'*')) AND
((tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnTax],'*')) AND
((tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnDistribution],'*')) 
AND ((tblISIN_Country_Table.Country) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text],'*')) 
AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0));
```

I have set up the various controls referenced by the query to run the same SQL statement above on the `_AfterUpdate` event of clicking the various dropdown fields. They all execute, which I can tell by a) the list box updating and b) by setting break points.

**The issues is this:**
When I change the value of the dropdown field for country for example, it filters by country. If I then set the dropdown field for Tax, it fileters for Tax, but ignores the value set in the country dropdown control (and all values in the other dropdowns as well).

**My question:**
Why does this happen and how can I get it to filter based on the values of ALL the dropdown fields at once?

Comment: Is this the query that all `_AfterUpdate` events run? Because I dont see a Filter on 'Tax' as you mentioned?

Comment: @Wouter Yes this is the query that all _AfterUpdate events run. I took out the Tax statement to experiment... sorry about that. I'll put it back in and update.

Comment: The SQL is basically not wrong as far as I can see. But you should not use HAVING for Filter (maybe it is the problem). Use it in a WHERE statement. HAVING is meant for aggregate functions, see here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Perhaps there is some other way, it involves a bit of vba coding. You can set the recordsource of the listbox to a query which you create in VBA. I've succesfully done this in a Subform before. You have to make a module which checks for every textbox is they are null or not. If not, you can create the filter in a variable after which you can combine all of the variables together.

Comment: One odd feature I just noticed in checking Sheils Barra's recommendation using `Debug.Print`. The filteres DO work together for the three dropdowns ddnTax, ddnRDR, and ddnDistribution... it's only when the ddnCountry that seems to ignore the others!

Comment: I solved it thank to everyone's comments and answers!

Comment: The issue was that the ddnCountry form had a bound column that referenced the wrong column. It didn't match the column that I was using the ListBox query! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in comment, try:

```
SELECT tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR AS [Retro Frei], tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status], tblISIN_Country_Table.Country

FROM (tblFUNDS INNER JOIN tblISIN_Country_Table ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblISIN_Country_Table.ISIN) INNER JOIN tblMorningstar_Data ON (tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection = tblMorningstar_Data.Fund_Selection) AND (tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblMorningstar_Data.ISIN)

WHERE (((tblFUNDS.RDR) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnRDR],'*')) AND ((tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnTax],'*')) AND ((tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status]) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnDistribution],'*')) AND ((tblISIN_Country_Table.Country) Like Nz([Forms]![frmMain]![ddnCountry].[Text],'*')) AND ((tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection)=0))

GROUP BY tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR, tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status], tblISIN_Country_Table.Country, tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection;
```

Comment: I just tried it, but I'm still getting the same effect.

Comment: Okay, I am sorrs it did not improve anything. The comment answer of @Wouter with vba is reasonable. I also use this method every time I need that. The SQL is shorter and you do not need NZ function in SQL

Comment: I kept your SQL... so thank you very much for that! In fact I managed to solve the problem just now. You and Sheils Barra and @Wouter certainly helped me in getting on the right track!

Comment: After having gotten the ListBox to sort properly, it caused a follow on problem, because I was using the same SQL query in a piece of code that now no longer worked... when I changed the SQL back to my original, the ListBox didn't sort correctly anymore. Which is a long way of saying: you provided the major piece of information in getting it to work correctly, which is why I'm marking this as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to state the obvious but are the values of the other textboxes still there after you have updates the country combobox? Try passing them to a message box or storing them in variables that you can watch to see exactly what parameter is being passed to the query

Comment: The values are there. I used `debug.print` to check. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear you've solved your problem. To elaborate my comment I will place the code to change the controlsource of the listbox here anyway. Maybe someone else will find it useful one day. Any comments are also welcomed.

```
Public Function Rapport_query()
Dim sqlTax As String
Dim sqlRDR As String
Dim sql As String
Dim selectQuery As String
Dim whereStatement As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer

'set counter (because if the filter is not the first there should be an "AND" operator before the filter.
i = 0

'check if the combobox is empty, if it's not use the input as input for you where statement
    If Not (IsNull(Forms!frmMain!ddnRDR)) Then
        i1 = i + 1
        sqlRDR = " tblFUNDS.RDR LIKE " & Chr(34) & Forms!frmMain!ddnRDR & Chr(34)
        i = i + 1
    End If

    If Not (IsNull(Forms!frmMain!ddnTax)) Then
        i2 = i + 1
        If i2 > i1 And i > 0 Then
            sqlTax = " AND tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence] LIKE " & Chr(34) & Forms!frmMain!ddnTax & Chr(34)
        Else
            sqlTax = "tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence] LIKE " & Chr(34) & Forms!frmMain!ddnTax & Chr(34)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End If

'if the lenght is 0, there are no filters. Else fill the where statement string
    If Len(sqlRDR & sqlTax) = 0 Then
        whereStatement = ""
    Else
        whereStatement = "WHERE " & sqlRDR & sqlTax
    End If

'set the select query
    selectQuery = "SELECT tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR AS [Retro Frei]," & _
"tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status]," & _
"tblISIN_Country_Table.Country " & _
"FROM (tblFUNDS INNER JOIN tblISIN_Country_Table ON tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblISIN_Country_Table.ISIN) " & _
"INNER JOIN tblMorningstar_Data ON (tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection = tblMorningstar_Data.Fund_Selection) " & _
"AND (tblFUNDS.ISIN = tblMorningstar_Data.ISIN) " & _
"GROUP BY tblFUNDS.MorningsStar_Fund_Name, tblFUNDS.ISIN, tblFUNDS.RDR," & _
"tblMorningstar_Data.[DEU Tax Transparence], tblMorningstar_Data.[Distribution Status]," & _
"tblISIN_Country_Table.Country , tblFUNDS.Fund_Selection"
'combine the select query with the variable where statement
    sql = selectQuery & whereStatement

'set the listbox controlsource
    Forms!frmMain.ListBox.ControlSource = sql
End Function
```

Comment: Change Function to Sub please

Comment: I made it a function because it is referenced through a macro, I wasn't able to reference a sub.

Comment: @Wouter Thanks for showing this. I may come back to it for a future case.

Comment: That is interesting. I did not know you can use a function without return type. Always learning something new. Nice

Answer (score 0):

For completeness's sake my answer so it is easier to find for someone else in the future:

The issue was that the ddnCountry form had a bound column that referenced the wrong column. It didn't match the column that I was using the ListBox query!