# Access VBA ApplyFilter

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access database I have a multiple search form with 3 search boxes:

- Name
- Surname
- Organization.

And VBA code on button Command368:

```
Private Sub Command368_Click()
On Error GoTo Command368_Click_Err

 DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Table_Name] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Form_Contacts]![Searchbox_name] & ""*"" And  [Table_surname] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Form_Contacts]![Searchbox_surname] & ""*"" And [Table_organization] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Form_Contacts]![Searchbox_organization] & ""*"" ", ""

Command368_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command368_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command368_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Is it possible to apply a filter only if one search box contains a text value which I want to search.

For example: If I write text in Searchbox_name, but Searchbox_surname, and Searchbox_organization are empty, I want to apply filter only on Name field.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032689/sql-query-ignores-controls-that-it-refrences/33034378#33034378

Answer (score 0):

You could check each control for a value Not IsNull or <> "" then build up a dynamic string that contains just the filter you need.

Problem here is you need extra checks for if there isn't a value don't add an AND

```
Dim strFilter
If Not IsNull(Searchbox_name) or Searchbox_name <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & "YourFilter"
ElseIf Not IsNull(Searchbox_surname) or Searchbox_surname <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & "YourFilter"
ElseIf Not IsNull(Searchbox_organization) or Searchbox_organization <> "" Then
    strFilter = strFilter & "YourFilter"
End If
```

ApplyFilter strFilter

The other option is an array, add to it if there is a value

```
Dim filters(3) As String
Dim filters(1) = "X like f"
```

Then loop the array building up the filter string with the value you need